# Why do eigenvalues exclusively form the main diagonal in a diagonalizable matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

So, why do eigenvalues exclusively form the main diagonal in a diagonalizable matrix?

If we have $n\times n$ matrix ($n$ being a natural number) that is diagonalizable, why is it eigenvalues (exclusively eigenvalues) that make up the main diagonal?

Comment: Because any number on the diagonal of a diagonal matrix is an eigenvalue of that matrix.

Comment: Do you mean "diagonal" instead of "diagonalizable"...?

Comment: It is true for $1\times 1$ matrices, but for larger sizes, a matrix that is diagonalizable need not have its eigenvalues on the diagonal.  Of course, if a matrix *is* diagonal, those diagonal entries are eigenvalues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not true, I think you mean diagonal matrix instead of diagonalizable. As an example you can take the 2x2 matrix $A$=$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2  \\ 
2 & 1 
\end{pmatrix}$, whose eigenvalues are $3$ and $-1$.

If you meant diagonal then you can check it almost from the definition.

Another way to check it is thinking that a matrix must have the same eigenvalues that its asociated diagonal matrix and then check the characteristic polynomial